# Windows path without spaces (with ~1)?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, path

I want to include the path to a library in the Program Files directory, but I need to do this without spaces.  I know that Windows uses a convention that shortens names like `Program Files` becomes `PROGRA~1`.  How can I find these shortened names for an arbitrary directory?

(Apologies if this has already been asked but I couldn't find it.)

Comment: Can't you just use quotation marks so you can leave the spaces in place? e.g., "C:\Program Files"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use for each folder:

```
DIR /X
```

Comment: also don't forget dir /x /a for hidden files

Comment: doesnt work on win 10

Comment: Doesn't this just show the short name for the file itself but not the folder ?

Comment: It will work on Windows 10.  I used Powershell and was in my home directory, which has a space between my first and last name.  I ran `DIR/X ..` and it spit out my shortened directory(s) I needed to see.

Comment: For me PowerShell didn't work in Windows 10, it gives me an error about being unable to find the `C:\X` directory. However, it works in good ol' cmd for me.

Comment: Did someone find the corresponding command for a PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

in cmd, go to required directory and type dir/x to see the shortened name for your required folder

Comment: Actually the directory above the required directory.

Comment: doesnt work in win 10

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to reference the Program Files folder : use the `%PROGRAMFILES%` variable. And there is no spaces in it :).
For instance : `%PROGRAMFILES%\MyLib\MyLib.dll`